# jquery ajax http status code

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am changing my scripts to jquery at the moment. This is my old javascript:

```
var request = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : (window.ActiveXObject ? new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") : false);
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.onreadystatechange = updatePage;
request.send(null);

function updatePage() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
                if (request.status == 200) {
                    var response = request.responseText;
                    doSomething();
                } else if (request.status == 304) {
                    doSomethingElse();
                } else {
                }
        }
}
```

I now want to change this to jquery-ajax:

```
request = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: updatePage
});
```

How can I test for the status code (and the responseText) returned by the request, like I did in my old script?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try this:

```
request = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    statusCode: {
      200: function() {
        doSomething();
       },
      304:function(){
        doSomethingElse();
       }
     }
});
```

or:

```
request = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    complete: function(e, xhr, settings){
       if(e.status === 200){

       }else if(e.status === 304){

       }else{

       }
    }
});
```

Comment: See my edit above, I really need the status code. Sorry if I didn't point that out correctly before.

Comment: How am I going to get the responseText now?

Comment: @Zulakis `200: function(dataText) {` or `complete:...text = e.responseText`

Comment: Hmm, i tried `statusCode: {
      200: function() {
        alert('Status 200');
       },
      304: function(){
        alert('Status 304');
       }
     }` but it is always alerting 'Status 200' even though I can clearly see that the Status is 304 in firebug.

Comment: Same with `complete: function(e, xhr, settings){
       if(e.status === 200){
   alert('Status 200');
       }else if(e.status === 304){
   alert('Status 304');
    }
 }`. Always alerts Status 200.

Comment: @mgraph Thank you for your answer. You are using three '=' (e.status === 200). Is this by purpose?

Comment: @MartinMeeserG.i.N. it's not required but preferred, to make sure it have the same type(int) and value(200)

Answer (score 1):

You need to just bind this request to an event like button click or something
Like

```
$('#btn').click({function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: updatePage
});
});
```

You dont need to really keep this request against a variable as **jQuery ajax** has a **success callback** which will help you to execute post success code

Comment: @Zulakis It also has a before handler which can handle your code before execution and success call back will handle after the execution.You still need other statuses?

Comment: Yes i need the other statuses as you can see in my question.

Comment: And I downvoted this because I was clearly asking for the status code in my question... Feel free to provide a answer to my question and I'm going to upvote you.