# Catch status code in jquery.form.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, http-status-codes

I'm trying to make a form debugger to my app, and using jquery.form.js to submit the form.

But I want to catch the status code on both success or error, how can I do it?

I tried this, but the sta variable only returns the 'success' or 'error', not the status code I expected, plz help.

```
$('form').ajaxSubmit({
    success: function(res, sta, xhr, $form) {
        $('#result-code').html(sta);
        $('#result-content').html(res);
    },
    error: function(res, sta, xhr, $form) {
        $('#result-code').html(sta);
        $('#result-content').html(res);
    }
});
```

---

as @Rainer Rillke replied: the solution is below, notice that the parameters sequence received of error is differ from the one with success!

```
$('form').ajaxSubmit({
    success: function(res, sta, xhr, $form) {
        $('#result-code').html(xhr.status);
        $('#result-content').html(res);
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        $('#result-code').html(xhr.status);
        $('#result-content').html(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: Assuming you are using [jquery.form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form) plugIn and want to capture the HTTP server status, use the `xhr.status` and `xhr.statusText` properties of the [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR).

Comment: @Rainer Rillke: I tried, but still cannot got it right, I updated the question, plz help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `xhr.status` property of the [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR).

```
$('form').ajaxSubmit({
    success: function(res, sta, xhr, $form) {
        $('#result-code').text(xhr.status);
        $('#result-content').html(res);
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        $('#result-code').text(xhr.status);
    }
});
```

Comment: I got undefined on both xhr.status and xhr.statusText.

Comment: Updated response. Your parameter order was wrong. Use `console.log(arguments)` if you are not sure what you get.

Comment: I got xhr to be a string of value "METHOD NOT ALLOWED" but not an object.

Comment: Oh, I found the point, the argument list is different, I have update the solution to the question, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's some kind of custom error that you're trying to catch, but if you're just trying to return the error that is coming from the web page, do a try/catch:

```
try {
     //do something here
}

catch (e) { //e = exception
     alert(e.toString());
}
```

Comment: The procedure don't even raise an error. I found the answer to the standard jquery function here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759627/jquery-ajax-http-status-code, but I'm using jquery.form.js plugin for ajax submitting the form. I want the solution in this case.

Comment: Names of jQuery plugIns aren't unique. Links are cheap.