# How to redirect user to login page when session is expired after AJAX call

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, session, session-state

I have following code that is working fine for most cases.

**But it doesn't work properly when session is expired and user execute some AJAX calls so it returns an error of AJAX.**

How it can be managed in a correct way?

Thanks!

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class SessionExpireFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public static String LoginUrl { get; set; }
        public delegate bool CheckSessionDelegate(HttpSessionStateBase session);

        public static CheckSessionDelegate CheckSessionAlive;

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {

            HttpSessionStateBase session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;
            if ((CheckSessionAlive == null) || (CheckSessionAlive(session)))
                return;


            //send them off to the login page
            var url = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
            var loginUrl = url.Content(LoginUrl);
            session.RemoveAll();
            session.Clear();
            session.Abandon();

            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(loginUrl, false);
            filterContext.Result = new EmptyResult();

        }
}
```

My current solution is following but is this correct one?

```
function UpdateSelectedProduct(uid, checked) {
      $lastProductUID = uid;
        var params = { uid: uid, isSelected: checked };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("UpdateSelectedProduct", "Orders")',
            data: JSON.stringify(params),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

            },
            error: function () {
                // alert("Timeout error.");
                document.location.href = "/";  // <---- Here it is
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: your solution would force the page to redirect to "/" on the JS side. Have you attempted sending the login url as part of the response? That way, you can grab it from the javascript errorhandler and redirect appropriately

Comment: You could check the status code in the error and redirect if it's unauthorized

Comment: @Jonesy It sounds good. Could you put some code example like an answer please?

Comment: look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759627/jquery-ajax-http-status-code)